Convolution and differentiation - two cascaded transfer functions
I'm just checking if the math I developed for a project is correct. I have two cascaded transfer functions named $H_{inv}(s)$ and $G(s,\hat{\theta})$. An input signal $u$ is convoluted with the cascaded combination of these two transfer functions:
$y = H_{inv}(s)G(s,\hat{\theta}) \ast u(t)$. I need to differentiate the whole expression with respect to $\hat{\theta}$, and, as seen, only $G$ depends on the parameter vector. I therefor have been doing the following:
$\frac{\partial y}{\partial \hat{\theta}} = \left[H_{inv}(s)\frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{\theta}}G(s,\hat{\theta})\right]\ast u(t)$. I just wanted to be sure if this is mathematically correct. (It works really good when tested as code, btw).
Note: $s$ is the Laplace variable and for this case $\hat{\theta}$ is not supposed to be time dependent, but to converge to a static value as an identification algorithm progresses.

Are s, theta both independent variable of t, or they can also be functions of t.

hi! I just edited my question to make it more clear, they are neither of them supposed to be time-dependent, this question regards LTI system identification actually
